# Marco al rededor de linear layout

Tags: android

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]En una aplicación android envuelvo el contenido de un fragment en un linearLayout.

Pongo todo lo necesario y con ancho `match_parent` pero cuando lo ejecuto, me deja como un marco al rededor de la pantalla, el cual no quiero que esté.

el linear layout lleva lo siguinete.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/fondo_pantalla"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="...">
```

También pasa con los componentes que están dentro de este linear layout. si lo pongo `match_parent` no llega del todo al borde de este,

paddin no tiene valores y margin solo donde los necesito.

¿Alguna idea?

Comment: Muestra el xml de la actividad donde llamas el fragment.

Comment: mabts, te saludo y te doy la bienvenida al sitio!, te invito a realizar el [tour] para 
conocer el funcionamiento básico del sitio y obtener tu primera 
[medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Con respecto a la realización de preguntas que estas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas excelentes respuestas, **es muy importante leer [ask]**,  saludos!

Comment: Puedes agregar imagen de como se muestra y el layout que carga el Fragment, por ejemplo el que contiene el Framelayout, etc! :)

Comment: Si, lo he editado para añadir la imagen. si te fijas a la izquierda del cuadro de usuario y contraseña hay un borde gris, hecho queriendo pero justo después hay otro un poco mas claro, ese es el que sale solo. sale rodeando

Comment: @mabts veo lo que refieres, en realidad es una tarjeta, tienes que agregar todo el layout del Fragment.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que muestras en tu imagen es un [CardView](https://material.io/guidelines/material-design/elevation-shadows.html#) con una elevación que permite mostrar una sombra y un espacio, para eliminar la elevación define esta propiedad con 0dp, `card_view:cardElevation="0dp"`.

Ejemplo:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

        ...
        ...
        card_view:cardElevation="0dp"
        ...
        ...
        >
```

Si tienes definida elevación o un padding entonces se ve de esta forma:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si eliminas la elevación o un padding definido, se mostraría de esta forma:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Gracias por los comentarios. finalmente era que todo estaba en un contenedor que era el que tenia los margenes.